# Get location value from array by passing businessName using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very naive user of Angular JS. So, far I'm able to get object from API and append to one of the textbox with business name, now when I try to select one business name the appropriate location name should be selected. But, I don't have idea how to get it.

For eg. if I select "sai Trading Limted", I need to get Koppal, or if I select "sindhura Traders" I need to get Raichur.

```
0: Object
location: "Koppal"
BusinessName: "sai Trading Limted"
1: Object
location: "Raichur"
BusinessName: "sindhura Traders"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="testController">
      <Select ng-init="traderIndex=''" ng-model="traderIndex">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="trader in traders" value="{{$index}}">{{trader.BusinessName}}</option>
      </Select>
    <div>The location is: {{traders[traderIndex].location}}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var testController = function($scope) {

  $scope.traders = [{
    location: "Koppal",
    BusinessName: "sai Trading Limted"
  }, {
    location: "Raichur",
    BusinessName: "sindhura Traders"
  }]

}
```

Check the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/46HLG40ToGlzEoG0iezq?p=preview